# Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() Error

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

Im receiving the following error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

Comment: Is store a string or an integer?

Comment: Put `mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in` into the search field. Then hit enter.

Comment: please verify that you have the proper mysql connection in place!!

Comment: also please check if $store is an int or string value!!

Comment: **Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).** They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). **Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)** instead, and **use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo).**

Comment: @SaurabhSinha $store is a string, The connection works as all my other queries work.

Comment: *"`$store` is a string"* - Treat it as one then.

Answer (score 0):

1. `$getholidays` isnt the result of `getholidayrequest()`

or

2. from the documentation:
   `mysql_query() will also fail and return FALSE if the user does not have permission to access the table(s) referenced by the query`

Comment: Sorry, i have updated the question. Please check the edit i have made

Comment: you need to check the `mysql_error()` then as @OussamaELGOUMRI said

Comment: I receive Unknown column 'Ealing' in 'where clause'

Comment: you should close $store in quotes if its a string
"SELECT * FROM `holidays` WHERE `store` = '$store'";

Answer (score 0):

you should check the mysql_query return value

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * WHERE 1=1');
if (!$result) {
    die('Requête invalide : ' . mysql_error());
}
```